# CSS Help: FlexBox childs padding

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to add padding to a flexbox child but it doesn't seem to work
My CSS code:

```
.template1 {
  background-color: rgb(89, 209, 52);
  width: 28%;
  height: 85%;
  margin: auto auto auto 50px;
  padding: 60px auto 60px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

The codepen: https://codepen.io/don0ts/pen/gjYJvq

Comment: there is no `auto` for padding use 0 instead

Comment: Thank you! Using padding-top, padding-bottom and so on properties worked for me. What you said made me figure that out!

Comment: @Temani It might be helpful for future users who have the same question if you post that as an answer (I know it's short, but it does answer the question!)

Comment: @Keara there is already a lot of questions dealing with this : https://www.google.com/search?q=padding+auto+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzu4u1kp7cAhWFPRQKHbuiBRcQrQIIMCgEMAA&biw=1600&bih=794

Comment: @Temani Fair enough. Is there a way to mark this question as a duplicate instead then?